# Issue with arender() in requests_html

Tags: web-scraping, python-asyncio

Trying to parse a website. The following code works:

```py
import requests, asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession


async def check_all():
    a_session = AsyncHTMLSession()

    await check_state(a_session)


async def check_state(a_session):
    id = "34965864"
    url_inspection = f"http://www.encar.com/md/sl/mdsl_regcar.do?method=inspectionViewNew&carid={id}&wtClick_carview=015"
    r_inspection = await a_session.get(url_inspection)
    # await r_inspection.html.arender()
    soup_inspection = BeautifulSoup(r_inspection.html.html, "lxml")
    inspection = soup_inspection.find_all("li", class_="uiLankNone")

    url_insurance = f"http://www.encar.com/dc/dc_cardetailview.do?method=kidiFirstPop&carid={id}&wtClick_carview=044"
    r_insurance = requests.get(url_insurance)
    soup_insurance = BeautifulSoup(r_insurance.text, "lxml")
    insurance = soup_insurance.find("div", class_="smlist").find_all("td")
    car_links = []
    if (
        len(inspection) == 5
        and insurance[-3].text.strip() == "없음"
        and insurance[-1].text.strip() == "없음"
    ):
        print(f"{id} is a clean car...")
        car_links.append(
            f"http://www.encar.com/dc/dc_cardetailview.do?pageid=dc_carsearch&listAdvType=normal&carid={id}&view_type=hs_ad&adv_attribute=hs_ad&wtClick_korList=019&advClickPosition=kor_normal_p1_g50&tempht_arg=F1nOMGQ319P7_49"
        )
    else:
        print(f"{id} had body repairs/been in accidents...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(check_all())

# a_session = AsyncHTMLSession()
# a_session.run(check_state)
```

However, when I run this with await r_inspection.html.arender() uncommented, it gives the RuntimeError: Event loop is closed.

I was able to run it this way though:

```py
import requests, asyncio
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession


# async def check_all():
#     a_session = AsyncHTMLSession()

#     await check_state(a_session)


async def check_state():
    id = "34965864"
    url_inspection = f"http://www.encar.com/md/sl/mdsl_regcar.do?method=inspectionViewNew&carid={id}&wtClick_carview=015"
    r_inspection = await a_session.get(url_inspection)
    # await r_inspection.html.arender()
    soup_inspection = BeautifulSoup(r_inspection.html.html, "lxml")
    inspection = soup_inspection.find_all("li", class_="uiLankNone")

    url_insurance = f"http://www.encar.com/dc/dc_cardetailview.do?method=kidiFirstPop&carid={id}&wtClick_carview=044"
    r_insurance = requests.get(url_insurance)
    soup_insurance = BeautifulSoup(r_insurance.text, "lxml")
    insurance = soup_insurance.find("div", class_="smlist").find_all("td")
    car_links = []
    if (
        len(inspection) == 5
        and insurance[-3].text.strip() == "없음"
        and insurance[-1].text.strip() == "없음"
    ):
        print(f"{id} is a clean car...")
        car_links.append(
            f"http://www.encar.com/dc/dc_cardetailview.do?pageid=dc_carsearch&listAdvType=normal&carid={id}&view_type=hs_ad&adv_attribute=hs_ad&wtClick_korList=019&advClickPosition=kor_normal_p1_g50&tempht_arg=F1nOMGQ319P7_49"
        )
    else:
        print(f"{id} had body repairs/been in accidents...")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # asyncio.run(check_all())
    a_session = AsyncHTMLSession()
    a_session.run(check_state)
```

However, I need the first way to work with arender() because I want to run asyncio.gather(*tasks) on check_state() function. Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When was `requests-html` last updated?

Comment: I've looked at this a bit and my conclusion is that `requests-html` is simply buggy. As Mr. Platipus hints in his comment, it looks as if the module is no longer maintained.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any suggestion on other libraries that could do this work?